# Generic Superclass and type mismatch

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, hierarchy

I have a generic base class:

```
public abstract BaseClass<T> where T: IMyModels {
     ...
}
```

And a subclass:

```
public class MyFirstsubClass: BaseClass<MyFirstModel> {
     ...
}
```

and these are the interfaces and model:

```
public interface IMyModel {} // Empty Interface 

public MyFirstModel: IMyModel {
   // Some automatic properties
}
```

Since `MyFirstClass` is extended to BaseClass whose type is implementing the `IMyModel` interface the below code must be fine but visual studio shows the "Cannot implicitly convert type" error and when I do the explicit cast it says the type cannot be explicitly cast.

```
BaseClass<IMyModel> Temp = new MyFirstsubClass();
```

What extactly is wring in this structure and how could I modify it so that the the problem  with the above code could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

> Since `MyFirstClass` is extended to `BaseClass` whose type is implementing the `IMyModel` interface the below code must be fine

No, a `BaseClass<MyFirstModel>` is *not* a `BaseClass<IMyModel>` since generic classes are not covariant by default.  Suppose you had a method:

```
public void Process(T model)
{
    ...
}
```

For a `BaseClass<MyFirstModel>` this method is compiled to

```
public void Process(MyFirstModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Now suppose you could cast it to a `BaseClass<IMyModel>`.  Then it would be legal to pass in some other implementation of `IMyModel` to `Process`, which is expecting *only* a `MyFirstModel` and could fail horribly.

> how could I modify it so that the the problem with the above code could be fixed?

The only thing you could do is declare it as a `BaseClass<MyFirstModel>` instead:

```
BaseClass<MyFirstModel> Temp = new MyFirstsubClass();
```

without knowing what `BaseClass<T>` does it;'s impossible to know if there's a reasonable way to convert it to a `BaseClass<IMyModel>`.

Comment: Well the confusion is because `IMyModel I = new MyFirstModel()` this is ok, if you remove the generic part then `BaseClass B = new MyFirstsubclass()`, but when adding the generic, theoretically that should work.

Comment: "without knowing what BaseClass<T> does" I need to have a `List<BaseClass<IMyModel>`

Comment: No it shouldn't.  A generic class with a derived generic parameter can't be cast to the same generic class with a base generic parameter for exactly the reason described.  [Generic _interfaces_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx) can be covariant but generic classes cannot

Comment: @Tom "I need to have a `List<BaseClass<IMyModel>`" that's not what I mean - what methods/properties does it have?  If all methods only _output_ `T`s then you could define a base interface and make _that_ covariant.  If any method allows inputs then there's no way to cast to a `BaseClass<{base class of T>`.

Comment: An interface would work, but the abstract class has a lot of methods that I can reuse in the subclasses so the could would be cleaner and well managed if using the BaseClass. But the problem is that I wrote another class that uses Dependency Injection by having a parameter of `List<Base<IModel>>` type. So problem is that I can't pass anything to that list.